# xargs pipe non empty stdin lines to command while preserving double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to have a script listen to stdin (so I run it and it doesn't immediately exit) and only execute when stdin is not empty and then pipe the stdin line to another command.
Right now I'm using the command from [the answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209249/piping-commands-after-a-piped-xargs):

```
xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {} | foo'
```

I want to preserve double quotes from stdin, for that people suggest using `-d '\n'` but this causes foo to run on empty lines.

I looked into possible GNU Parallel solutions but couldn't find anything.

Here is my stdout:

```sh
>xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {} | foo'


bar
I have executed for 'bar'

"bar"
I have executed for 'bar' //notice the double quotes missing
^C
>xargs -I {} sh -c "echo '{}' | foo"

bar
I have executed for 'bar'

"bar"
I have executed for 'bar' //Same thing, double quotes missing
^C
>xargs -d '\n' -I {} sh -c "echo {} | foo"

i have executed for '' //doesn't ignore empty lines anymore

i have executed for ''
bar
i have executed for 'bar'
"bar"
i have executed for 'bar'
```

Desired output:

```
bar
I have executed for 'bar'

"bar"
I have executed for '"bar"'
```

Running

```
echo '"bar"' | foo
```

gets me

```
I have executed for '"bar"'
```

Comment: `xargs sh -c '...{}...'` causes serious security problems. Yes, you see people do it all the time, but don't contribute to the problem by doing it yourself. (Same is true of `find ... -exec sh -c '...{}...' \;`). Data should always be passed out of band from code to avoid injection attacks -- not just in bash but everywhere else as well.

Comment: Which is to say, follow tripleee's advice. 

Answer (score 1):

If, as your tags suggest, you are running on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), you have GNU `xargs`, which supports the `-0` option. Then, you can pass in completely arbitrary text, including even newlines:

```
printf '%s\0' "foo" "'bar"' '"baz"' 'quux
with a newline' | xargs -0 foo
```

Removing empty lines could be accomplished with a simple `grep` in front.  There is also `xargs -r` which says to not run the command if `xargs` receives empty input (this too is a GNU extension).

Your attempts are slightly problematic, though; you should pass the arguments as command-line arguments rather than have `xargs` interpolate them into the `sh -c '... {} ...'` string literally.

Slightly depending on your requirements, this could even work portably on other platforms:

```
xargs sh -c 'if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then echo "$@" | foo; fi' _
```

The `_` is just a placeholder; the arguments to `sh -c '...'` are used to populate `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc and so we put in something, anything, to occupy the slot for `$0`.

Comment: I would pass `sh` as `$0` so that if there are any errors they're printed as `sh: <error message>`.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel uses this internally:

```
perl -e 'if(sysread(STDIN,$buf,1)){open($fh,"|-",@ARGV)||die;syswrite($fh,$buf);if($read=sysread(STDIN,$buf,131071)){syswrite($fh,$buf);}while($read=sysread(STDIN,$buf,131072)){syswrite($fh,$buf);}close$fh;exit($?&127?128+($?&127):1+$?>>8)}' /usr/bin/bash -c 'wc -l'
```

If you only want a single line try:

```
seq 3 | parallel --pipe -N1 wc -c
echo "'foo'" | parallel --pipe -N1 --rrs "echo -n i have executed for \"'\";cat;echo \"'\""
echo '"foo"' | parallel --pipe -N1 --rrs "echo -n i have executed for \"'\";cat;echo \"'\""
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to preserve double quotes from stdin, for that people suggest using -d '\n' but this causes foo to run on empty lines.

`xargs` performs quote processing by default unless you specify a delimiter via either `-d`/`--delimiter` or `-0`/`--null`.  You *must* use one of these to avoid `xargs` removing the quotes you are trying to preserve.

What's more, supposing that you manage to pass the quoted input through `xargs` unchanged, the shell that xargs launches to run the command will perform its own quote removal, as well as parameter expansion, variable assingments, redirection processing, *etc*.  You can observe the effects of that directly with this variation on your command:

```
$ xargs -d '\n' -I{} sh -c 'echo {} >>tmp.txt' 
bar
'bar'
$ cat tmp.txt
bar
bar
$
```

Note that the quotes are removed despite specifying a delimiter to `xargs`.

---

It's a bit hard to parse your exact requirements, but it sounds like you just want to filter empty lines out of the standard input to some command.  `sed` can do that pretty easily:

```
foo() {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "I have executed for '$line'"
  done
}

$ sed '/\S/!d' | foo


bar

"bar"
A whole line with "quotes" and 'quotes' and metacharacters > < !
I have executed for 'bar'
I have executed for '"bar"'
I have executed for 'A whole line with "quotes" and 'quotes' and metacharacters > < !'
$
```

**Explanation of the `sed` command**: the regex `/\S/` matches any non-whitespace character, anywhere on the line.  The `!` negates the match, and the `d` deletes lines matching the (negated) pattern -- that is any line that does not contain at least one non-whitespace character.

As you can see in the example run transcript, there is a difference in buffering between your example command and the effect of filtering with `sed`.  It's unclear whether that's important to you.